# Why don't the thread start and run methods return anything?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am wondering why the Thread.start (existing JDK1.0) method is designed not to return an object. I understand devs can use callable which is similar but came into existence much later i.e JDK 1.5.  I recognize people can use a workaround like passing a result container in thread constructor to contain the thread result but again I am wondering why it was not designed to return a result.

Am I am missing anything here?  Is it good in terms of design (such as eliminating the need explicitly to return the null even when it was not required) or is it a design
flaw?

Comment: What should the method return in your opinion? I can not imagine a general solution that would be appropriate for most threads. Also, most of my threads are not even designed to return results. I mean the only goal of using threads is to execute code in parallel. And there are plenty of situations where you want to execute code that does not return a result. Also returning a result implies that there is some kind of *monitoring process* that joins the results, there are also many situations where you don't have this.

Comment: So the default solution is to return **void** but you are allowed to extend the `Thread` and introduce a result field with your own result class together with a `getResult` method. For example a class like `ThreadWithResult extends Thread`. I don't know why they designed `Callable` the way they did, you can probably argue for both version - with result and without. A possible reason could be the introduction of **generics** because without them a "`Callable<Object>`" just is not comfortable to use.

Comment: To answer your question `What should the method return in your opinion`, way like  callable. Probably that was not possible in JDK1.0 as generics came into existence much later

Comment: Yeah, they came with **version 1.5**, exactly where `Callable` came. So, would also be my guess.

Comment: and how are you going to use that result?

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.start()` merely starts thread execution and returns.  Normally on return the thread is still executing, or even waiting to start execution, so there is no result to return yet. Since there is nothing to return at that point, it makes sense not to have `Thread.start()` return anything.

`Thread.run()` is not normally called by your code, since calling it would run the method in an existing thread rather than running it in a new thread.  Rather, `Thread.run()` is called by the Java virtual machine (JVM) in the new thread after the JVM has created that new thread.  The JVM code of course has no idea what your thread is supposed to do and would not know what to do with a return value, so `Thread.run()` does not have a return value either.

Answer (score 0):

There is really nothing to return. `Thread.start()` only "puts" this thread to internal execution scheduler. It does NOT mean that thread immediatelly starts to execute code. When internal scheduler decides that thread is ready to execute - it will start executing code from `run()` method - and of course can switch to execute another thread anytime.